# How to set a default folder for downloads from facebook in htc desire 816?

Tags: htc-desire, facebook

When downloading a pic from fb, it automatically saves in the camera gallery in htc desire 816. Where to set an option for default folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for that. Sorry